# Diff and exchange JSON value between default and actual response

Tags: javascript, json, traversal, javascript-objects

I have 2 JSON object **default** and **actual**, they can be NESTED. I want to write an javascript algorithm to compare and exchange the value between default and actual. But I am stuck and only able to process the outermost level of the JSON

Here are the example:

Default:

```
{
   username : "string",
   phone    : null,
   school   : "string",
   GPA      : {
     major  : null,
     minor  : null
   }
}
```

Actual:

```
{
   username : "David",
   phone    : 12345,
   school   : "Harvard",
   password : "david@harvard"
   GPA      : {
     major  : 3.9
   }
}
```

after the diff and exchange value the result should be:

```
{
   username : "David",
   phone    : 12345,
   school   : "Harvard",
   GPA      : {
      major : 3.9,
      mimor : null
   }
}
```

The idea is have the default model, if the response have extra property such as password, the algorithm should remove such property.

On the other hand, if the response doesn't have the require property, the algorithm should fill in the default value.

So the final result should only contain the keys that define in the default model, and the value will come from the response, if a key does not exist use the default key value pair.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, then $.extend() can be used to accomplish this.

```
var def = {
   username : "string",
   phone    : null,
   school   : "string",
   GPA      : {
     major  : null,
     minor  : null
   }
}

var actual = {
   username : "David",
   phone    : 12345,
   school   : "Harvard",
   password : "david@harvard",
   GPA      : {
     major  : 3.9
   }
}

var extended = $.extend(true, {}, def, actual);
```

Here's a jsfiddle that should demonstrate this.
https://jsfiddle.net/38L808y1/

Comment: This is a good answer but the password is still within the result, and I process this on Node server so jquery is not an option